# Failed to install a package from GitHub: System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed,

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am trying to install a package from GitHub using devtools but I get `'Rcmd.exe'` failed. How to get around with this? Many thanks in advance.

```
   devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")


Error: Failed to install 'tidyr' from GitHub:
  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: -1, stdout + stderr empty
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\seyma\OneDrive\Belgeler\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\magrittr\libs\x64\magrittr.dll to C:\Users\seyma\OneDrive\Belgeler\R\win-library\4.1\magrittr\libs\x64\magrittr.dll: Permission denied
```

Additional Information,

```
> library(devtools)
Loading required package: usethis
> find_rtools(T)
Found in Rtools 4.0 installation folder
[1] TRUE
> session_info()
- Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  English_United States.1252
 ctype    English_United States.1252
 tz       Europe/Berlin
 date     2022-03-11
 rstudio  2022.02.0+443 Prairie Trillium (desktop)
 pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/ (via rmarkdown)

- Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 cachem        1.0.6   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 callr         3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 cli           3.1.0   2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 crayon        1.5.0   2022-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 curl          4.3.2   2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 desc          1.4.1   2022-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 devtools    * 2.4.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 digest        0.6.28  2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 knitr         1.37    2021-12-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 pkgbuild      1.2.0   2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 pkgload       1.2.4   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 processx      3.5.2   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 ps            1.6.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 remotes       2.4.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 rmarkdown     2.13    2022-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
 rprojroot     2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 testthat      3.1.0   2021-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 usethis     * 2.1.3   2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
 xfun          0.27    2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)

 [1] C:/Users/seyma/OneDrive/Belgeler/R/win-library/4.1
 [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to install the development version of `tidyr`? If so, you may find some help with this error [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-resolve-install-github-fails-with-error-system-command-rcmd-exe-failed-exit-status-1-stdout-stderr/95202).

Comment: I was actually hoping to find another solution without doing a hard reset, but it works out for me after resetting my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread because I had the same problem. Installation from github was not possible, no matter what I tried, I had the "System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed" Error.

I finally found the solution here: https://copyprogramming.com/howto/problem-with-rcmd-exe-when-installing-packages

After removing (or renaming at first for safety reasons) the registry key

**\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun**

the installation via devtools and github is finally working again!

I have struggled with this problem for so long. I don't know if this the solution for everyone having this problem, but for me it worked. Hopefully this post can help soneone coming across this thread in the future.